# Problemas para gerar arquivo pdf e equações no arquivo via R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, rmarkdown

Estou tentando rodar a seguinte função via R Markdown, buscando gerar um pdf, e com equações utilizando o LaTeX

Já instalei todos os pacotes necessários, assim com o MiKTex 2.9 versão completa

````
    ---
title: "Aula 02 - Formatação de Texto"
author: "Henrique Oliveira"
date: "03/07/2019"
output:
  pdf_document: default

---

#Formatação de Texto 02

O Jailson, mais conhecido como *pai de familia*

O Jailson, mais conhecido como **pai de familia**


\* = *Itálico*

\*\* = **Negrito**

\`\` = Formata igual código 

##Exemplo 02

Para você obter os primeiros dados de um vetor, usar a função `head()`


# Aula 3 - Listas


### Lista ordenada
1. Arroz
2. Feijão
3. Batata

### Lista não Ordenada

* Arroz
* Feijão 
* Batata

### Sublista

1. Arroz
2. Feijão
3. Calzone
    + Coxinha
    + Pão de Batata
    + E mais


# Aula 04 - Criando links no R MarkDown

Caso queira entrar no site da [Perfin](http://www.perfin.com.br/asset/)


# Aula 06 - Fórmulas Matemáticas

Para incluírmos as fórmulas matemáticas no documento, usar `$$ LaTeX $$` (bloco) ou `$LaTeX$` (na linha)

## Exemplos

$$

\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}

$$

$$

  \forall x \exist y(F(x,y)) \to Q(y,x))


$$

$$


  s = \sqrt{\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N(x- \bar{x})^2} {N -1} }


$$



# Aula 07 - Executando o Código no R Markdown - Bloco de Código

Você pode criar blocos inline ou em bloco

## Bloco

```{r eval=TRUE}

head(mtcars)


```


## Inline

``r x<-c("Zurubabel");x ``



# Aula 08 - Configurando os blocos de código

Podemos configurar os blocos de código com algumas flags. Elas podem possuir o valor `TRUE` ou  `FALSE`.

## Flags

### Eval

o `eval` habilita ou não a execução do código
com `eval = FALSE` o código não será executado e possíveis valores não serão armazenados

``` {r eval = TRUE}

str(x <- "churros")

```

``r x ``


### echo

O `echo` mostra o código junto ao resultado.

```{r echo=TRUE}

str(mtcars)


```



### warning

O `warning` exibe possíveis advertências ou mensagens no código

```{r warning=TRUE}

warning("Era essa a peça que você queria ? ")



```



### error 

`error` oculta ou não as mensagens de erro do seu código. Se `FALSE`

```{r error=TRUE}

c(


```

Se quiser colocar mais flags, só ir inserindo no campo de flags


# Nomeando e executando os blocos de código

Após o comando ``r{`, você pode nomear o bloco de código.

#### Exemplo

```{r chulesco, eval = FALSE, echo=FALSE}
#Criando o código

modelo_arima<-arima.sim(model = list(c(0,0,0)), n = 50)

plot(modelo_arima)

```


``` {r ref.label = 'chulesco' }
#Criando 



```


# Aula 10

#Possíveis Configurações


* `html_document`
* `pdf_document` - caso não funcione, baixar e instalar o pacote MiKTeX
* `word_document`
* `beamer_presentation`
* `slidy_presentation`
* `ioslides_presentation`
* `word_document`
````

Mesmo com tudo instalado corretamente , recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
    output file: Aula_02.knit.md

    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.221 \sqrt{
                \frac{a}{b}} 

    Try to find the following text in Aula_02.Rmd:
      \sqrt{ 

    You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in Aula_02.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
    Erro: Failed to compile Aula_02.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Aula_02.log for more info.
    Execução interrompida
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema está na notação do LaTeX. Altere suas fórmulas para

```
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$

$$\forall x \exists y(F(x,y)) \to Q(y,x))$$

$$s = \sqrt{\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N(x- \bar{x})^2} {N -1} }$$
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a maneira correta de escrever o operador de existência é `\exists`, com um s ao final.

Há três maneiras principais de escrever fórmulas no LaTeX:

1. Na própria linha da fórmula, com o símbolo `$` colocado apenas uma vez: `$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$`
2. Como uma linha nova, centralizada e sem numeração, em um bloco afastado do texto:

   ```
   $$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$$
   ```
3. Como uma linha nova, centralizada e com numeração, em um bloco afastado do texto e sem `$`:

```
\begin{equation}
a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
```

A vantagem do modo 3 é que a equação pode ser referenciada posteriormente, caso seja atribuído um label para ela:

```
\begin{equation}\label{pitagoras}
a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}

Como podemos ver na equação \eqref{pitagoras}, temos que o quadrado da hipotenusa é igual à 
soma do quadrado dos catetos.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.